# I can't to return json objects using Axis2

Tags: java, xml, json, web-services, apache-axis

I can't to return json objects using Axis2 like web service. I added the lines of builder and messageFormatter in my web2.xml for the support json but always that access my web service to test return in xml.

I use the url to test my action: http://server.com:8080/webservice/services/classe/action?response=application/json but no success.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Any code you can show to know what you're trying?

Comment: Nothing, always return in xml. But, Now I solve my problem. In my modules folder (WEB/INF/modules) missing the wso2dynamic response module. Now added the wso2dynamic-responde-1.5.jar and wso2dynamic-responde-v.mar. Thats solved for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve your problem exporting the wso2dynamic response (wso2dynamic-response-1.5.jar and wso2dynamic-response.mar) to modules folder (WEB/INF/modules).