# JSON response from Axis2 Web Service

Tags: wso2, apache-axis

I am developing web service using `Axis2`, creating `.aar file` and deploying it in `WSO2 Application Server.`  The Axis2 services deployed successfully and returns me the response as below.

```
<ns:serviceResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.axis.example.com">
    <ns:return>{"status":"SUCCESS"}</ns:return>
</ns:serviceResponse>
```

But I am expecting a JSON response. Since Axis2 has support for JSON response, I tried following the below tutorial by modifying axis2.xml(Enabling `messageBuilder and messageFormatter`) but it was not successful.
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/json_support.html
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/json-web-service-with-java-and-axis2.html
Also,
I tried deploying `wso2dynamic-response-20080916.170559-241.mar` from UI (`Modules Tab -> Add`) and the uploaded file deployed to the following location(CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/axis2modules).
And I tried copying `wso2dynamic-response-1.5.jar` as per suggestion in [I can't to return json objects using Axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656147/i-cant-to-return-json-objects-using-axis2) but still getting XML response instead of JSON.

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong and guide to the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you manage to get the solution to your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @SovereignSun - Apologies. I don't remember the solution since it was 10 years ago. Over this period of time I believe the WSO2 would have evolved a lot. Please check the latest version documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would 
JSONMessageFormatter.getJSONWriter
Help?

Comment: Elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling JSON message formatter in the axis2.xml should work..Anyway , what is your response's content type?..It should be application/json

Comment: I am sending GET request by appending the query string response=application/json and response content type is application/xml. I even tried with the echo service available in WSO2 server by hitting the following URL. http://localhost:8280/services/echo/echoInt?in=7&response=application/json and I am getting only XML response and not JSON response like the following. <ns:echoIntResponse><return>7</return></ns:echoIntResponse>. Also, I have the following question. Do I need to place the wso2dynamic-response-1.5.jar file? And if Yes, In which folder? Thanks.

Comment: if your service responds with JSON responses, you dont need to do any additional change other than the message formatter change. What is that "wso2dynamic-response-1.5.jar"? it might be an older implementation, and you dont need that.

Comment: My Java class will return JSON string like {"status":"SUCCESS"}. And my response from Web Service is <ns:serviceResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.axis.example.com"><ns:return>{"status":"SUCCESS"}</ns:return></ns:serviceResponse>. As u could see JSON string inside ns:return element. Also, I followed the following URL(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656147/i-cant-to-return-json-objects-using-axis2) where they suggested to put wso2dynamic-response-1.5.jar file(I removed it now). Let me know any other configuration needed.